# fullcalendar 4.0 use loop to set events dynamically

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm trying to use the full calendar to set an event dynamically.By using function loadData().But I couldn't work successfully.
Could anybody please let me know how to solve this problem?

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var temp_array = loadData();
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        schedulerLicenseKey: 'GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source',
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        header:{
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth'
        },
      plugins: [ 'interaction','dayGrid' ],
        for (let i = 0 ; i <temp_array.length ; i++){
            calendar.addEvent({
                title: temp_array[i][0],
                start:temp_array[i][1],
                end :temp_array[i][2]               
            })
        }

    });
    calendar.render();

  });

function loadData(){
    let temp_array=[];
    temp_array[0]=["test1","2019-07-16","2019-07-21"];
    temp_array[1] = ["test2","2019-07-15","2019-07-20"];
    temp_array[2] =["test1","2019-07-16",""];
    return temp_array;
}
```

I tried this it throws an

> exception: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Answer (score 1):

```
plugins: [ 'interaction','dayGrid' ],
        for (let i = 0 ; i <temp_array.length ; i++){
            calendar.addEvent({
                title: temp_array[i][0],
                start:temp_array[i][1],
                end :temp_array[i][2]               
            })
        }
```

You cannot put a `for` loop inside an object like that. You can pass events as an array to calendar's config: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-array

EDIT:
If you want dynamic events, you can also pass a function: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-source-object#options

Comment: but i want to set events dynamically ,when i increase the data size of temp_array

Comment: i tried event :function(){calendar.addEventSource({...})}, it called calendar.addEventSource is not a funciton

Comment: You do not need to call `addEventSource`, you just need to return an array from event function.

Comment: @TonyHuang this is probably what you need: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function

Comment: i tried this way , but i didn't work correctly function loadData(){
......
var events = [];
 for (var i = 0 ; i<temp_array.length;i++){
  events.push({
   title:temp_array[i][0],
   start:temp_array[i][1],
   end:temp_array[i][2]
  })
 }
 return events;
}
then document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
....
var events = loadData();
...
event :events
..
}

Comment: @TonyHuang that isn't how the link I provided suggests to do it